# How is SIP scaled for high load?

Tags: scalability, sip, voip, p2p

Basically, I want to implement a VoIP system with sip in a vps server. But it seems that it would not be able to handle more than ~20 simultaneous calls(just bare sip). What are the workarounds to this problem? Can the sip server be just used as a database to tell the clients where to find their intended targets..? Like p2p? I am quite new to sip. Additional info is appreciated.

Comment: So what SIP proxy are you using? Sounds like it is trying to do media proxying too, not just signalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIP scalability comes from delegating as much work to the endpoints and doing as little on the servers as possible.
What you describe is a "redirect server": it accepts and stores registrations from the endpoints (softphones, hardphones, etc), and responds with "3xx redirect" to incoming calls and forgets about them immediately.

This is probably the most extreme example of server minimization. SIP is a very versatile protocol, it lets you set up your server infrastructure in many different ways with varying degree of control over calls. It lets you trade off features for performance.

Even the flimsiest VPS should be able to handle the signalling for way more than 20 parallel calls even in full "stateful proxy" mode.

Just make sure media (the RTP streams) is not routed through your server. Set up STUN to help firewalled endpoints send media to each other directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPS server looks to pretty low-key and when you say it cant handle more than 20 Cps that seems to indicate it topped out on CPU. Correct me if thats not the case.

Options to Scale SIP

1. Of the Shelf SIP Load balancer - Available in Virtual / Hardware / Opensource and every flavor that you want. It hides a farm of SIP Servers that you have and it can be managed to spread the load accordingly.
2. Unless the nature of SIP server is defined, it can be difficult to understand the bottlenecks you face and without that its difficult to give a simple solution.